# Where can I find just a responsive grid system

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid-system

I have started a new project and I need (only) responsive grid for layout.
I have tried with http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/ this grid system and it's fine but it adds some classes for inputs and other elements that I don't need and it makes a mess in some of my forms.
I am looking for any solution.
I need just responsive grid that will not mess with other elements.
Is there any such framework?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use display:flex , setting `min-height` `min-width` for childs to keep safe minimal size where little content.:

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wFHfq

In order to see IE 10/11 , working too , you need to add a width or height to main container. Most of the time `width:100%` will do , here i setted `height:100%` on `body`.

**This will not work for older browser, you may use vendor-prefix and old syntax to increase compatibility.** here is something to [read](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/) and here [too](http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/) .

```
body  div {
  display:flex;/* flex it */
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  min-width:320px;
  min-height:160px;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px white, 2px 2px 3px;
flex:1;
}
html,body {
  height:100%;/*IE*/
  margin:0;
}
body>div {
  min-height:100%; 
}
div div {
background:pink;
}
div div:nth-child(even) {
  background:lightgray
}
```

BASIC HTML TEST:

```
<div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

Comment: fill it with content to test it :)  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/full/fCzew

Answer (score 0):

try [semantic.gs](http://semantic.gs/)

> Set column and gutter widths, choose the number of columns, and switch between pixels and percentages.
>
> All without any .grid_x classes in your markup. Oh, and did we mention it's responsive?